# Failed to load kafka module

Tags: apache-kafka, nxlog

I am trying out the nxlog kafka out module from below

[Link](https://github.com/filipealmeida/nxlog-kafka-output-module)

I get the below error message

```
ERROR Failed to load module from /usr/local/libexec/nxlog/modules/output/om_kafka.so, /usr/local/libexec/nxlog/modules/output/om_kafka.so: undefined symbol: rd_kafka_topic_new;DSO load failed

ERROR module 'outKafka' is not declared at /usr/local/etc/nxlog/nxlog.conf:65

ERROR route tcproute is not functional without output modules, ignored at /usr/local/etc/nxlog/nxlog.conf:65
```

I am using :

> Nxlog Version - nxlog-ce-2.8.1248
>
> Kafka Version - kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1
>
> Latest librdkafka

Also the example programe of librdkafka (rdkafka) for both producer and consumer runs fine so I guess the environment is set correct for librdkafka , 
but am unable to determine what's  causing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that om_kafka.so is not linked with librdkafka.
You will need this in Makefile.am:

> om_kafka_la_LIBADD       = $(LIBRDKAFKA) $(LIBNX)

The value of $(LIBRDKAFKA) should be properly set ,normally this is done in configure.in. Otherwise you could just use the full path to the library (.so or .la or .a )